# Xcode 4 Crashes frequently

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I just downloaded XCode 4 on my Mac Air running Snow Leopard. It crashes all the time! I believe I can recreate the issue most every time by following these steps:

- Hold Option key and click on an Object/Method etc. to open documentation. 
  I am presented with a login screen to enter my Apple Dev Credentials but an error dialog appears.
- Click 'Continue'
  I get the documentation
- Debug application
  A dialog appears telling my XCode has crashed.. Game over

This is happening on my Mac i5 as well as my Mac Air. It crashes frequently enough that it is almost unusable. Is there a workaround that anyone has found?

Holy cow.. how did this ship? :)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Xcode ;)

Comment: Oh really? Haha  I fairly am new to this IDE. But XCode 3 wasn't this bad

Comment: Xcode 4 is a great improvement over 3. It really is a great IDE, but as you've noticed, it can be pretty buggy at times and does crash often.

Comment: Have you tried a restart/re-install yet?  Xcode is running great on my core2duo MacBook pro (that might have something to do with the SSD, but hey ;)

Comment: @CodaFi Yeah.. I'm actually running this on a Mac Air core2Duo with SSD. It crashes there as well. No, I have not tried to reinstall it.. I guess I can. Its stable on your on your system.

Comment: "Xcode 4 is a great improvement over 3" -- not everybody will agree with that. I know people clinging on to Xc3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it resolved! So as it turns out the documentation is not installed by default when doing a clean install of XCode4. So I installed it locally and my issues went away. Heres what I did:

- Go to Xcode preferences
- Click "Downloads"
- Click the "Documentation" tab
- Install the Documentation (I just installed it all)
- Restart xcode (I noticed the documentation would not open till I did this)

Now when I visit the documentation I do not get directed to online documentation and the crashing is gone.